# Checkmarx vulnerability - if embeds untrusted data

Tags: javascript, code-injection, checkmarx

I have this code:

```
                _addIconForDropDownMenu : function() {
                    if (this.getConfig('tabDropdownMenu')) {
                        $(this.$root.find('span.ossui_dropdown_icon'))
                                .closest("li").remove();
                        $(this.menuIconTemplate)
                                .insertAfter(
                                        this.$root
                                                .find(
                                                        ".ossui-pagetabs-nav-bar .ossui-addtab-icon")
                                                .closest('li'));
                        this._createDropdownMenuOnOverflow();
                    }
                },
```

and i get this checkmarx issue:

```
The method if embeds untrusted data in generated output with $, at line 4567 of ui.js. This untrusted data is embedded into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the generated web-page. Similarity ID: -2086290339
```

I didn't understand what this checkmarx mean and how to solve it.
I tried to use GPT and he changed my method to be like this:

```
_addIconForDropDownMenu: function() {
    if (this.getConfig('tabDropdownMenu')) {
        // Sanitize or encode the untrusted data before using it with jQuery
        var untrustedData = ''; // Replace this with the source of untrusted data

        // Example of sanitization (assuming untrustedData is a string)
        var sanitizedData = sanitizeFunction(untrustedData);

        // Example of encoding (assuming untrustedData is a string)
        var encodedData = encodeHTML(untrustedData);

        // Example usage with jQuery ($)
        $(sanitizedData).closest("li").remove();
        $(encodedData).insertAfter(
            this.$root.find(".ossui-pagetabs-nav-bar .ossui-addtab-icon").closest('li')
        );

        this._createDropdownMenuOnOverflow();
    }
},

// Example function to sanitize data (sanitizeFunction)
function sanitizeFunction(data) {
    // Implement your sanitization logic here
    // Return sanitized data
}

// Example function to encode HTML entities (encodeHTML)
function encodeHTML(str) {
    return str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(match) {
        return {
            '&': '&amp;',
            '<': '&lt;',
            '>': '&gt;',
            '"': '&quot;',
            "'": '&#39;'
        }[match];
    });
}
```

and still i don't understand what is this checkmarx, where can be injection? and the GPT solution.

Tnx

Comment: I don't think there's anything bad in your code. An attacker could add malicious HTML code if you e.g. you have something like `.insertAfter(\`<p>${responseFromServer}</p>\`)`, but in your case you are querying an element from the DOM and inserting it to the DOM again, thus you don't need to sanitify it since it's already trusted

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina tnx what i thought